# Remove line entirely (not to leave it empty)

Tags: regex, expression, line

This is what I have in doc:

```
1;01878916;BC101;FALSE
16;01978916;BC101;FALSE
17;0195B4E5;BC101;FALSE
19;0197D016;BC101;FALSE
```

After I run find&replace: `^((1|17);.+?)$` with: `empty` it leaves

```
blankrow
16;01978916;BC101;FALSE
blankrow
19;0197D016;BC101;FALSE
```

and then I have to run find and replace `\s+$` in order to remove empty line(s) and manually remove first empty line.

Im weak with regex, tried to combine those 2 commands into one.
How it should be, to remove entirely empty rows, without leaving empty row?

To get

```
16;01978916;BC101;FALSE
19;0197D016;BC101;FALSE
```

Thanks in advance. I need to have regex commands in order to run FIND and Replace in all open files, because I'm doing this in 10 files at once. Line operations > Remove blank lines is not an option.

Comment: try `^((1|17);.+?)(\r?\n|$)`

Comment: `^(1|17);.+?\s+` should work

Comment: Both solutions work, thank you guys, this is nowhere near what I tried :)

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: `(1|17)` is the same as `17?`, just make the `7` optional.

Answer (score 0):

The regex:

```
^(1|17);.+?\s+
```

mentioned above works well here as there is no whitespace at the beginning of the lines you want to keep. If that's ever not the case, you can also do:

```
\s+^(1|17);.+?$
```

Comment: I think you missed $ in the end, `\s+^(1|17);.+?$` i need to capture entire row until end, this is similar to previous ones, thanks for tip